# Angular2 - как работает route

Tags: angular2, angular-routing

Как работает маршрутизация(RouterModule)? 
Припустим у меня есть:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: 'customers', canActivate: [GuardNavbarService], component: CustomersComponent },
{ path: 'orders', canActivate: [GuardNavbarService], component: OrderComponent }
];
```

Я не пойму как при нажатии на ссылки ('customers' и 'orders') будут подгружаться компоненты (CustomersComponent и OrderComponent)-имееться ввиду кусок html вида. Эти компоненты запрашиваються с сервера или ,грубо говоря, они все уже есть в клиента и при нажатии на ссилку один компонент показываеться а другие прячуться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing в Angular2 работает следующим образом. Вы создали константу с роутами, в них указали компоненты, пути к ним и свойство canActivate (это не полный список). При переходе на путь, Routing сравнивает его с текущей константой, где хранятся пути и если находит схожий инициализирует компонент, который к нему привязан. Никакой подгрузки нет, т.к. скомпилированный код Angular2 находится в одном основном файле и все html-темплейты находятся уже подгруженными, а Angular2 только их инициализирует и показывает в нужный момент. Свойство canActivate указывается тогда, когда вы хотите указать особенно условие перехода на данный роут. Например неавторизованным юзерам не показывать компонент личного кабинета. 
Думаю достаточно понятно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я уже разобрался методом проб и ошибок, но всеравно галочка!

Answer (score 0):

Ничего с сервера не запрашивается. Ангулар строит приложение по принципу SPA - single-page application (одностраничное приложение).
В составе Ангулар есть директива , которая показывает, что на ее место будет подставлен html-тейплейт (кусок html) компонента. 
Вот RouterModule как раз и устанавливает соответствие компонента при нажатии на ссылку.